# Original cracked laptop screen works. New one goes off after a minute

Tags: hardware-failure, laptop-display

I have cracked screen on Lenovo S400. With this cracked screen, laptop works as excepted.

When I install replacement screen, laptop works for about a minute and then the display goes black. It is possible to light it on again for a short time by using a harware key "turn LCD on/off" (first press - obviously nothing happens; second press - screen goes on for about three seconds).

It seemed to me that the screen I bought is faulty, so I went to the shop and they tried about five different replacement screens from various manufacturers and they all behaved the same as the first one. They said they even tried loading firmware from the cracked screen to the new one.

The problem does seem to have some relation with temperature. When I start notebook after a long period of time (cooled down), the replacement screen stays on for about a minute or two. On the second try, it is just about 10 or 15 seconds. **And this interval stays this short even when trying different (not heated up) replacement screen immediately.**

I have really no idea what is going on, nor the guy in the screen shop. Does anybody have a clue what might be a problem?

I will post further details if needed, thanks.